# Nomenclature not showing

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

I'm composing a Master's Thesis on TexMaker.

There is a Thesis.tex file which calls for every other file (Chapters, Thesis_Abstract, Thesis_Acknowledgements, Thesis_Dedication, Thesis_FrontCover, Thesis_Preamble, Thesis_Nomenclature and several Appendices).

In the Nomenclature file, I really don't have any text. Just comments made by the students (that provided these .tex files) preivously formatted to the Universities guidelines for Dissertation on all the related parts (FrontCover, Bibbliography, etc.).

However, I do have (on Thesis.tex) the command:

\printnomenclature

And on the Thesis_Preamble.tex:

\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

And the Nomenclature section is still not showing. I mean, on the side structure, when reading the TexMaker compiled pdf, it shows Thesis_Nomenclature, but when it is nowhere to be seen on the actual pdf.

What am I missing to make the Nomenclature section appear?

PS: the nomenclature entries are written in the following format:

\nomenclature[prefix]{symbol}{description}